# R ggplot barplot with people name over it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data-frame like below for 4 years:

```
State        Sex Year     Name   Percent
Arizona      M    1962     John   0.3
Arizona      F    1962     Mary   0.6  
Arizona      M    1963     Peter  0.4
Arizona      F    1963     Jane   0.9
Arizona      M    1964     Dave   0.7 
Arizona      F    1964     Lara   0.3
Arizona      M    1965     Den    0.7 
Arizona      F    1965     Kate   0.2
```

I need a barplot with people name over it for every year but only with two colors like green and red.
One example is like below:

[image]

So in my case:

- x-axis are Years
- y-axis are Percent

Numbers over barplot are people names and instead of blue I need red and green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. The only problem is the position of the text labels : you have to compute them beforehand. My solution assumes there are only two observations a year and that they are ordered M first, F second.

```
txt <- readLines(n=9)
State        Sex Year     Name   Percent
Arizona      M    1962     John   0.3
Arizona      F    1962     Mary   0.6  
Arizona      M    1963     Peter  0.4
Arizona      F    1963     Jane   0.9
Arizona      M    1964     Dave   0.7 
Arizona      F    1964     Lara   0.3
Arizona      M    1965     Den    0.7 
Arizona      F    1965     Kate   0.2
df <- read.table(text=txt,head=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- group_by(df,Year) %>% 
  mutate(pos=ifelse(Sex=="M",Percent,Percent+lag(Percent)))

ggplot(df,aes(x=Year,label=Name,fill=Sex)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=Percent),stat="identity",position="stack") +
  geom_text(aes(y=pos),vjust=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx scoa. Tried not working for me. when I run df <- group_by(df,Year) %>% 
  mutate(pos=ifelse(Sex=="M",Percent,Percent+lag(Percent))) I get column pos with NA for females

Comment: yes sure. I get pos values same as percent for males, but NA for females. My barplot shows only male names, some of them instead of females

Comment: are they ordered M first F second for each year? `lag()` takes the previous value in a group, so if F is first, it will fail. In that case, replace it by `lead()` (next value) or `last()` (last value in group)

Comment: This was the mistake. I changed M to F and everything OK. Thank you very much. Is there any way I can play with the colors of bar-plot,  position and font of names?

Comment: use `+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","green"))` to set the color ; for the text, see the options size, family and fontface in `?geom_text`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all in `ggplot` with `stat_summary` to place the text as well.  The key is to use the `cumsum` to get the y-positions.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Percent, fill=Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  stat_summary(aes(label=Name, order=desc(Sex)), fun.y=cumsum,
               position='stack', geom='text', vjust=1)
```

[image]